# CSS Attribute selector not working on <li> element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to target an `<li>` tag based on its title attribute but it is having no effect:

```
<style>      
[title~=Client PPT Presentation] {
display: none;
}
</style>
<li title="Client PPT Presentation">
</li>
```

Title is is a global attribute and I verified sytntax, so why isn't this working?

Comment: `~=` is used for searching for 1 word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~=` operator is used to select elements with an attribute value containing a specified word

Example:

```
[title~='Client'] {
  display: none;
}
```

If you want to check for a string value (not a single word) you have to use the `*=` operator which is used to select elements whose attribute value contains a specified value

```
[title*='Client PPT Presentation'] {
   display: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

you should select it using `[title="Client PPT Presentation"]`

see http://jsfiddle.net/ngzck7bp/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<style> 
li[title="Client PPT Presentation"] {
    display: none;
} 
</style>
<li title="Client PPT Presentation">
</li>
```

I believe this is what you need.
You should honestly have just read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) though.